# Python: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop and create a new data frame based on another data frame I have. Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
Foo Fizz Buzz totals scale
10  3    2     15     .2
8   4    3     15     .2 
5   1    5     11     .4
6   7    5     18     .1
9   2    6     17     .1
```

And a categorical variable as such:

```
groups = pd.Series(['Foo','Fizz','Buzz'], dtype = "category")
```

And I want to create a new dataframe where it takes the percentage of the total and multiply it by the scale. I figured the easiest way is to loop it so I can have the dataframe and names consistent but it's throwing me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

The code I used is below. Any help would be appreciated (I know there has to be an easier way). Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty data frame 
for j in Categorical(groups).categories: #looping through categories
    calc = [] #empty list
    for i in range(0, demo.shape[0]): #loop through rows
        #Below is basically the column divided by the total and multiplied by the scale. 
        #Then take that number and append it onto the list                    
        calc.append(round((round(cross.ix[i,j],4)/round(cross.totals[i],4)) * cross.weight[i],4))

        #finally append this list to the dataframe using the categories as the column name using setting with enlargement 
        df.loc[:,Categorical(groups).categories[j]] = calc
```

Comment: you could check the value of demo.ix[i,j]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
round(   (demo.ix[i,j],4) / round(demo.totals[i],4)   )
```

I've added spaces to your code to emphasize what's happening: you have a `tuple` of `demo.ix[i,j]` for one element and `4` for the other, then you divide that `tuple` by `demo.totals[i]` rounded to 4 places (a `float`), then you round that... only you can't round that because attempting to divide that `tuple` by a `float` gives the error you saw. Try the following instead.

```
round(demo.ix[i,j],4) / round(demo.totals[i],4)
```

Comment: So I tried your suggestion using
 `calc.append(round(demo.ix[i,j],4) / round(demo.totals[i],4) * demo.scale[i])` 

and I get an error something along these lines

 `pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7193)()`

`KeyError: 3`

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I see what you are trying to explain. Thanks!